# Reverse animation when clicked if hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to slide a "toggle button" to the left after the navigation bar hides and slides left and then slide it back to the original position when showing navigation bar.  Here's what I'm trying currently.

This does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $toolbar = $("#toolbar");
  var $toggle = $("#toggle");

  $toggle.on("click", function() {
    if ($toolbar.is(":visible")) {
        $toolbar.toggle(500);
        $toggle.animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500);
    } else if ($toolbar.is(":hidden")) {
        $toolbar.toggle(500);
        $toggle.animate({
            left: 20.5%
        }, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

When I remove the animate method on the else block everything seems to work, when I add it back to reverse the "$toggle" button to the original position none of the code works.... any help is much much appreciated!!

EDIT: added snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $toolbar = $("#toolbar");
  var $toggle = $("#toggle");

  $toggle.on("click", function() {

 if ($toolbar.is(":visible")) {
  $toolbar.toggle(500);
  $toggle.animate({
   left: 0
  }, 500);
 } else if ($toolbar.is(":hidden")) {
  $toolbar.toggle(500);
 }
  });
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/*===============================================*/

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 background-image: url(../images/boatsunset.jpg);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#shoppingCart {
 background-color: #00000000;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 1rem;
 position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   border: none;
}

#shoppingCart img {
 height: 3rem;
 width: 3rem;
}

#toolbar {
 color: #000000;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 font-size: 3rem;
 position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   width: 25%;
   display: inline-block;
}

#toolbar ul {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85%;
}

#toolbar li {
 margin: 2rem auto;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#toolbar li:hover {
 color: #aaaaaa88;
}

#toggle {
 background-color: #00000000;
 border: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 left: 20.5%;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 3rem;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#toggle:hover {
 color: #aaaaaa88;
}

#listborder {
 width: 80%;
 border-right: .2rem solid #aaaaaa55;
 height: 26rem;
 position: absolute;
 top: 51%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   z-index: -1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href= "assets/stylesheets/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="description" content="Artwork by Gia dalPozzo">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Gia dalPozzo, Gia, dalPozzo, artwork, fine art, paintings, oil painting">
  <meta name="author" content="Marlin dalPozzo">
  <title>Gia dalPozzo | Home</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/script1.js" async></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header>
   <button id="shoppingCart"><img src="assets/images/cart2.png"></button>
  </header>

  <div id="toolbar">
   <ul>
    <li>Florals</li>
    <li>Landscapes</li>
    <li>Portraits</li>
    <li>My Story</li>
    <li>Events</li>
    <li>Contact Me</li>
   </ul>
   <div id="listborder"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="toggle">
   <p><</p>
  </div>

  <footer>
   <!--social media links/icons-->
   <!--copyright etc-->
   <!--date updated-->
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to add complete code or create a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for better responses

Comment: Post your `HTML` code. And a jsfiddle will be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `left` property of the button as a string. Using the "%" symbol like you did is not allowed in JavaScript. The correction looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $toolbar = $("#toolbar");
  var $toggle = $("#toggle");

  $toggle.on("click", function() {

 if ($toolbar.is(":visible")) {
  $toolbar.toggle(500);
  $toggle.animate({
   left: "0"
  }, 500);
 } else if ($toolbar.is(":hidden")) {
  $toolbar.toggle(500);
    $toggle.animate({
      left: "20.5%"
    });
 }
  });
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/*===============================================*/

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 background-image: url(../images/boatsunset.jpg);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#shoppingCart {
 background-color: #00000000;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 1rem;
 position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   border: none;
}

#shoppingCart img {
 height: 3rem;
 width: 3rem;
}

#toolbar {
 color: #000000;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 font-size: 3rem;
 position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   width: 25%;
   display: inline-block;
}

#toolbar ul {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85%;
}

#toolbar li {
 margin: 2rem auto;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#toolbar li:hover {
 color: #aaaaaa88;
}

#toggle {
 background-color: #00000000;
 border: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 left: 20.5%;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 3rem;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#toggle:hover {
 color: #aaaaaa88;
}

#listborder {
 width: 80%;
 border-right: .2rem solid #aaaaaa55;
 height: 26rem;
 position: absolute;
 top: 51%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   z-index: -1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href= "assets/stylesheets/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="description" content="Artwork by Gia dalPozzo">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Gia dalPozzo, Gia, dalPozzo, artwork, fine art, paintings, oil painting">
  <meta name="author" content="Marlin dalPozzo">
  <title>Gia dalPozzo | Home</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/script1.js" async></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header>
   <button id="shoppingCart"><img src="assets/images/cart2.png"></button>
  </header>

  <div id="toolbar">
   <ul>
    <li>Florals</li>
    <li>Landscapes</li>
    <li>Portraits</li>
    <li>My Story</li>
    <li>Events</li>
    <li>Contact Me</li>
   </ul>
   <div id="listborder"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="toggle">
   <p><</p>
  </div>

  <footer>
   <!--social media links/icons-->
   <!--copyright etc-->
   <!--date updated-->
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

JQuery can handle that as you see.

Comment: *facepalm*  jeeze.  life of a noob... thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your markup it is kind of difficult as the other posters have mentioned, but I'll yolo it without seeing your source.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $toolbar = $("#toolbar");
    var $toggle = $("#toggle");

    $toggle.on("click", function() {
        $toolbar.animate({
            width:'toggle'
        }, 750);
    });
});
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3rbj19n9/

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I included the html and css now.  thats close and something i've tried already toggling the width.  it's not the actually toolbar i'm having problems with it's having the hide/close toggle button animate with the rest of the bar so that when the toolbar is hidden the toggle button is resting on the left edge of the webpage